# How to get region of user in loggs Django

Tags: django, logging

I'm looking for way to get info about which region user from and add that in logg file

I already can have their ip with function

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return str(ip)
```

And then i add that into logg info

```
def writing_logs(request, action):
    logger.info('{} {} {} {}'.format(
        request.user.email,
        get_client_ip(request),
        action))
```

And i want to know how to do something like that and show country/region/city of request user

Comment: You can look into this tutorial about how to use third party APIs to get country information: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-location-information-of-ip-address-using-python/